# How could I generate random colors from this SCSS function?

Tags: html, jquery, css, sass

This function gives me output in `#ff0063`, but I'm trying to accomplish a plethora of colorful pixel dots on the screen. If possible could someone describe what exactly is going on in the code?

```
@function multiple-box-shadow ($n) {
  $value: '#{random(2500)}px #{random(2500)}px #ff006e';
  @for $i from 2 through $n {
    $value: '#{$value} , #{random(2500)}px #{random(2500)}px #ff006e';
  }
  @return unquote($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `random()` function in SASS returns you a number from 1 to the argument you provided. Therefore the code in the question is creating multiple `box-shadow` values at random positions up to 2500px away from the original element.

To add random colours to the logic, provide 3 `random(255)` arguments to `rgb()`, like this:

```scss
@function multiple-box-shadow ($n) {
  $value: '#{random(250)}px #{random(250)}px #ff006e';
  @for $i from 2 through $n {
    $value: '#{$value} , #{random(250)}px #{random(250)}px rgb(#{random(255)}, #{random(255)}, #{random(255)})';
  }
  @return unquote($value);
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ykh82mon/)

Note that the demo uses up to 250px for the random positioning to make it fit on the screen better.